# How to kill(or update) track-to/aim constraint for camera with Python API

Tags: python, objects, camera, constraints, tracking

I can track objects with camera constraints. I want to update object which we aimed(tracking new objects). So, I tried to update target object of the constraint but it does not work. Now, I am trying to kill camera constraint but camera should be remain so I would set it to track another object. The camera constraint code shown below.

```
cam_data = bpy.data.cameras.new('camera')
cam = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', cam_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cam)
cons = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
cons.target = track_object
scene.camera = cam
```

Comment: Do you mean that the constraint isn't updated when you change its `target` ?

Comment: Yes, it still aim old target.

Comment: Your code fragment doesn't show how you set `target_object`.  Are you sure it's set to the right object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fragment is missing two things:

1. How you set the `scene` variable.  I'll assume you wanted the active scene and use

```py
scene = bpy.context.scene
```

2. How you set the `track_object` variable.  I'll assume you wanted the active object and use

```py
track_object = bpy.context.active_object
```

With those two changes, your code looks like

```py
import bpy

track_object = bpy.context.active_object
scene = bpy.context.scene

cam_data = bpy.data.cameras.new('camera')
cam = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', cam_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cam)
cons = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
cons.target = track_object
scene.camera = cam
```

and when I run it it creates a camera with a Track To constraint set to point at the active object in the scene I created.

[image: Camera track to constraint pointing at active object]

When I later execute

```py
cons.target = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]
```

and I have a Monkey in the scene, the Track-To target changes to the Monkey.

So your problem seems to be that you haven't set `track_object` to the object you want as the target.

EDIT:

Here is a Blend file with a cube and a monkey. I've modified the code to use the cube rather than the active object as the first target of the track to, but you can double check my work.  It's a 3.0.1 file, but should work just fine in any Blender version since 2.8

[image]

Comment: My code is almost same like you provide. My problem is not tracking an object. My problem is tracking a new object after tracking an old object. I mean, after your code try to track a new object, it would not work.

Comment: It works fine with my code if I write something like `cons.target = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]` and I have a Monkey in the scene, it will switch the target to to the Monkey.

Comment: Really, it does not work on mine. Ok, I'll try again.

Comment: Perhaps you've done something in your code so that `cons` is no longer the track-to constraint?  Try running all of your code in the Python console.  You should see the target in the track-to change when you run the second bit of code.